# Error installing Photo2Shape QGIS 2.6 for Mac

Tags: qgis, photo2shape, exifread

I am trying to install the Photo2Shape plugin for QGIS on a Mac (10.9 Mavericks) but I am getting the following error:

The plugin is broken. Python said:
No module named exifread

I have installed exifread using pip install exifread from inside Terminal, but the plugin is still having issues finding the module. Is there a way to link modules inside of QGIS? Or is there other options?

Comment: Where did you install the [ExifRead](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ExifRead) module ? The QGIS version of Kyng Chaos use the Apple Python (modules installed in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages)

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, as I am a new convert to Mac from Windows. I used terminal to install ExifRead, so I am not sure where it "went". Is there a manual process I can do, to ensure it goes where it needs to? I do not have that path /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages  I do not even have the Python folder.

Comment: Thanks @gene. I think I resolved it, the folders were hidden. I downloaded the module and placed it in the site-packages location. Thanks for the help