# installing exifread for photo2shape plugin

Tags: installation, exifread

I've already seen https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138207/error-loading-plugin-photo2shape-even-after-installing-exifread-module and [Error installing Photo2Shape QGIS 2.6 for Mac](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124660/error-installing-photo2shape-qgis-2-6-for-mac), but cannot make it work.

First I installed pip, and then went to c:\python27\scripts and typed "pip install exifread", and it got installed. See

[image: screenshot1]

you can see that it is "up-to-date".. but when I try to install photo2shape it insist:

> no module named exifread

Comment: look at [QGIS Standalone and the Python Modules](http://quantumofgis.blogspot.be/2014/11/qgis-standalone-and-python-modules.html)

Comment: Thank you, but I have tried already and did not work

Comment: It was much easier in Ubuntu. Although I would like to solve the problem in my windows PC, I will use photo2shape in my Linux PC. So, that's it. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Id did not use pip but extracted it manually and afterwards added the path to that folder.

Try creating a new file "exiftools.pth" in the folder "C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages" (or any other folder that is configured within the QGIS python-path environement) with just one line of text containing the path to the folder where your exiftool files are located. You may need admin privileges to do so. In my case that file would contain the following line:

C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages.

4. Restart QGIS for an update of the pythonpath environement.

Answer (score 2):

This was for a mac.  I wound up downloading exifread manually here - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ExifRead.  I then copied the sub directory to /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python.  Afterwards I restarted QGIS and was able to install the photo2shape plugin sucessfully.

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded the files from the website mentioned by hlinak and then extracted them to the folder nominated by Daniel. After a quick reboot all was well.